# Matrix Representation Theorem with Differentiation Question

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I am trying to figure out the logic as to why finding $D(e^x), D(xe^x), D(x^2e^x)$ gives the column vectors for $A$.

I tried to work backwards by plugging in a $f$ which would be some vector in the span of $e^x,xe^x.x^2e^x$ into $D(f)= Af$ but I don't see how a matrix $A$ can be multiplied by a function $f$ to get the derivative.

Comment: You should start by writing $f$ as a linear combination of your basis vectors: $$e^x = (1, 0, 0)^T, xe^x = (0, 1, 0)^T, x^2e^x = ( 0, 0,1)^T$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way one builds a matrix from a linear operator $T$, say on a dimension $3$ vector space, is
$$
A_T=\begin{bmatrix} \vert&\vert&\vert\\T(e_1)&T(e_2)&T(e_3)\\\vert&\vert&\vert  \end{bmatrix}
$$
That is all that is going on here.

To see why, note that $A_T(e_i)=T(e_i)$.

Comment: Usually the size of matrix A is $mxn$ but how can we tell the size is 3x3 when it is a differentiation operator on S, a subspace of $C[a,b]$

Comment: because the subspace given to you is a three dimensional one. Namely, everything in the subspace can be written as $\alpha e^x+\beta xe^x+\gamma x^2e^x$ for suitable constants $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$.